# Why do Prague streets use double street addresses?

Tags: czech-republic

I'm traveling to Prague and I noticed that every street has double addresses, one red and another blue. What's the story behind that?

[image]

Comment: Related to [What do the additional numbers on the side of houses in Rome stand for?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95009/what-do-the-additional-numbers-on-the-side-of-houses-in-rome-stand-for) which is about Rome but Prague is mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Although I'm glad this is here, because I find it interesting, if I were the one noticing it, I would have asked someone who lives there.

Comment: ...you should also check out slovakia... we are cool too... ;(

Comment: @GregHewgill, the difference is that, as far as I can tell, Czechia and Slovakia are the only two countries where both numbers are used together (always, if both exist—villages may not have the second) in official addresses.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The upper number is the "descriptive number" (Czech: číslo popisné or č. p.) and is unique within each municipal part (in this case, Nové Město, Praha 1).

Since descriptive numbers can be fairly large and since they're generally assigned based on age (i.e. newer houses have higher numbers), they're hard to use for navigation, which is where the second number comes in.

The lower number is the "orientational number" (Czech: číslo orientační or č. o.). It's unique for each street or square (in this case, Wenceslas Square) and can be used for navigation, since houses in a row should have increasing numbers based on their position in the street/square. Also, for streets, houses on one side of the street have even orientational number, and odd on the other side.

The same system is used in other towns and cities in Czechia. The plaques can have different colors, but their position (the orientational number below the descriptive number) should be consistent.

See also [the *House numbering* article on the English Wikipedia, section *Czech Republic and Slovakia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_numbering#Czech_Republic_and_Slovakia).

Side note: while the Czech names for these numbers are clear, I found different English translations. Some translate číslo popisné as "conscription number" and some translate číslo orientační as "reference number". I have chosen to go with the more literal translations.

Comment: _"houses in a row should have increasing numbers based on their position in the street/square. Also, for streets, houses on one side of the street have even orientational number, and odd on the other side."_ this is common in other countries and a good thing to keep in mind when navigating streets.

Comment: Czechia? I've never heard that before.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_the_Czech_Republic

Comment: I never understood what those descriptive numbers were for, they appeared too random to have anything to do with addresses. Mighty fine answer.

Comment: @Marianne013, how do you pronounce the ch here? As ch in school or ch in chicken?

Comment: @jf328 the Wikipedia article includes pronunciation: "the English equivalent "Czechia" /ˈtʃɛki.ə/"

Comment: @svick I've heard the upper number referred to as "register numbers", as they are used mainly in the land register to identify a particular asset (building, land area, etc).